# SwiftUI DatePicker is not displaying the initial value

Tags: swift, swiftui

I created a custom Date Picker to be able to pick a nil value.

This is the code:

```swift
struct ProfileEditDateField: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    var label: String
    var placeholder : String
    var isMandatory: Bool
    
    @State private var hiddenDate: Date
    @Binding var date: Date?
    @Binding var requiredFields: [String: Bool]
    
    init(label: String, placeholder: String? = "", date: Binding<Date?>, isMandatory: Bool, requiredFields: Binding<[String: Bool]>, keyboardType: UIKeyboardType = .default) {
        self.label = label
        self.placeholder = placeholder ?? ""
        self._date = date
        self.isMandatory = isMandatory
        self._requiredFields = requiredFields
        self._hiddenDate = State<Date>(initialValue: date.wrappedValue ?? Date())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8.0) {
            if isMandatory {
                Text(label + " *").font(.custom(Fonts.ROBOTO_REGULAR, size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray)
            } else {
                Text(label).font(.custom(Fonts.ROBOTO_REGULAR, size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            
            ZStack {
                HStack {
                    DatePicker("", selection: $hiddenDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                        .onChange(of: hiddenDate, perform: { _ in
                            self.date = hiddenDate
                        })
                    Button(role: .destructive, action: {
                        self.date = nil
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: SFSymbols.CLOSE_SQUARE_FILL)
                    })
                }
                
                if self.date == nil {
                    Button(Resources.getString(Strings.NO_DATE_SELECTED)) { }
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .frame(height: 35, alignment: .trailing)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                        .background(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.black : Color.white)
                        .allowsHitTesting(false)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: date, perform: { _ in
                if isMandatory {
                    requiredFields[label] = date == nil
                }
            })
            
            Divider().frame(height: 1).foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
        .onSubmit {
            if isMandatory {
                requiredFields[label] = date == nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't matter how I set the initial value of hiddenDate, the Picker always shows the current and hiddenDate will be 01-01-2001.

[image: The Custom Date Picker.]
[image: The State value.]

How can I make the DatePicker to show the correct hiddenDate value?

Comment: My guess your binding doesn't work right. The `self._hiddenDate = State<Date>(initialValue: date.wrappedValue ?? Date())` looks weird. Usually if `hiddenDate` if a Binding, and you pas it in as `date: Binding<Date?>`, then you assign it as `self._hiddenDate = date` - that's it

Comment: @timbretimbre I just tried the code in other View and it works as intended, I guess I have an error in the parent view that the binding is not working as intended as the value is not being passed.